# Unix nslcd login with sAMAccountName and/or userPrincipalName from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, authentication, freebsd, ldap

I'm trying to setup authentication from Active Directory in FreeBSD 10.0 using nslcd (nss-pam-ldapd-sasl package) and would like to allow both sAMAccountName and userPrincipalName as valid login attributes in the server.

I don't know if it's possible to use this specific configuration.

Here are my actual mappings in `/usr/loca/etc/nslcd.conf`

```
# Do not allow uids lower than 1000 to login (aka Administrator)
nss_min_uid 1000
# Disallow disabled accounts to login
pam_authz_search (!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))

#filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)))
#map passwd uid sAMAccountName
filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=*)(!(objectClass=computer)))
map passwd uid                  userPrincipalName
map passwd uidNumber            objectSid:S-1-5-21-NULL-NULL-NULL
map passwd gidNumber            primaryGroupID
map passwd gecos                displayName
map passwd homeDirectory        "${unixHomeDirectory:-/home/$sAMAccountName}"
map passwd loginShell           "${loginShell:-/bin/tcsh}"

filter group (objectClass=group)
map group cn                    sAMAccountName
map group gidNumber             objectSid:S-1-5-21-NULL-NULL-NULL
```

I'm not sure if I should modify `nslcd` or what I'm looking should be achieved with `pam`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is you don't. You will need to use sAMAccountName, that is a username. Can you imagine what a mess with usernames you will have on your linux box? let's just say you have a user Linus (principal name) and linust (username) how your system should make UIDs based on those names, and will UIDs be the same? Authentication using ldap needs to be done using username and password.

Comment: Hello Dmitriy I moved on to SSSD. And it worked. Actually the userPrincipalName is unique just like the sAMAccountName. The UPN is in name@somedomain format, so it is unique.